# Using Google.Cloud.Firestore in a .NET Class Library

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuget, .net-standard, class-library

I have a Class Library built in .NET Standard 2.1 that references [Google.Cloud.Firestore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.Firestore) installed with NuGet.

The project compiles without issue. However, the output DLL does not contain Firestore nor does the output folder contain any other DLL dependency.

I *could* use `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies` in my csproj in order to output all of Google.Cloud.Firestore. However, it gives me 27 additional files totaling over 4mb in additional data.

Is there an easier way of using Firestore in a .NET class library without all of the additional overhead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [dotnet publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish).

It should copy the application's dependencies `Google.Cloud.Firestore` to the output folder.

`dotnet build` may not do it, depending on the .NET version being used.